# Не появляется подменю при наведении на ссылку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, list

Сразу привожу код - http://jsfiddle.net/FPrp9/1/

```css
#menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 135px auto;
    background: url(../images/menu_background.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 3px 0 4px 0;
}
#menu > ul {
    height: 24px;
}
#menu > ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 95px 0 64px;
    background: url(../images/menu_decor.png) no-repeat right center;
    position: relative;
}
#menu > ul .last_child {
    background: none;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#menu > ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    font: 20px BookAntiqua;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/menu_background_hover.png) no-repeat right center;
    top: 43px;
    left: 35px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
}
#menu ul li ul li:first-child {
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.php">О кафе</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="menu.php">Меню</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.php?kitchen=europe">Европейская</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="menu.php?kitchen=japan">Японская</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last_child"><a href="contacts.php">Контакты</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что при наведении на ссылку "Меню", должно появляться подменю, но оно появляется, только если его показ применить не к `a`, а к `li` (см. последнее CSS-правило). Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## menu ul li a:hover + ul
>
> Используйте [плюс](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает и я разобрался в проблеме. Я не правильно интерпретировал свое правило.

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu ul li a:hover ul
```

у вас же вложенный список находится внутри li, а не в "a", именно поэтому данное правило не работает